# Calling an excel macro from build script

Tags: c#, excel, msbuild, build-process

I am looking to call an excel Macro as part of a build script.  I was trying to use powershell to call into excel.  I was using the following article as a reference:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept06/hey0908.mspx

This approach did not work due to the fact that there seems to be a bug that only allows for en-us Culture to work this way.

What other possibilities is there for call a macro from a build script?  I would really appreciate it if you could point me in the direction of any articles for reference.

Comment: call excell as part of a build script? sounds crazy to me...

Comment: We keep client static data in an excel spreadsheet and generate bulk insert scripts from it, this works very well as clients can update the spreadsheet with little or no effort.  Currently it is a manual step to generate the files but all manual steps have risk associated with them so we are trying to minimize risk.

Is that so crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the data out of it you can open an OleDbConnection connection to the spreadsheet and get the data then perform the inserts yourself. If your spreadsheets contain more than just plain data then you can use Excel Automation for this (but this is not supported for non-interactive apps).

Sayed